# Three different ways to express the idea "X, if not Y"

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

> Ce qu'ils ont découvert est troublant, **pour ne pas dire** effrayant.
>
> Ce qu'ils ont découvert est troublant, **si ce n’est** effrayant.
>
> Ce qu'ils ont découvert est troublant, **sinon** effrayant.

The phrase "pour ne pas dire" immediately comes to mind when I want to say "X, if not Y". But how do the other two similar phrases "si ce n’est" and "sinon" compare? Are all three interchangeable?

Comment: The first two are grammatical, the third is not. The first two mean the same thing. But sinon is not if not. Sinon is a coordinating conjunction. Ils doivent aller à l'école, sinon ils auront des problèmes. It can also go at the end and it means otherwise. not, if not.

Comment: @Lambie I don't agree with you, nor does Larousse, see third definition: http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sinon/72888. As far as I know, all 3 sentences are totally similar and interchangeable.

Comment: http://www.espacefrancais.com and then add to it slash /les-conjonctions-de-coordination-et-de-subordination/  Sinon is a coordinating conjunction. The others are not. Sinon functions like the in the list in the link. pour ne pas is not a coordinating conjunction neither is si ne c'est.

Comment: @Lambie Sinon is a coordinating conjunction indeed, but not only. In this case, it seems not to be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three are interchangeable !
The first one means

> I'm saying that this is disturbing, but I could have said that this is frightening

the second means

> if this is not frightening, this is disturbing

and the last one means

> if this is not disturbing, this is frightening.

As a french person I use the second one more ! But an other common way to say this sentence is:

> Ce qu'ils ont découvert est troublant, **voire** effrayant.

Which means "I'm saying that this is disturbing, I could have said that this is frightening but it's maybe too much", it's not exactly the same meaning but we often use it to say "X, if not Y"

Comment: Je me suis permis d'éditer la réponse pour des corrections mineures, n'hésitez pas à rééditer si vous n'êtes pas d'accord avec ces modifications, ce ne sont que des suggestions :)

Comment: +1 for noting their interchangeability & for “voire" but re the translations, I see them all as falling under [CNRTL’s 1st entry for “sinon”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sinon) [I.A.1.a)=”Exprime l'exception hypothétique ... avec idée de **gradation**”=“la quasi-certitude de B rend A incontestable” (& NOT “b)=de concession")] which tempts me to give all 3 the sense of “.. is troubling [to say the least] & perhaps even frightening.” Your first 2 capture that, but I’m not sure the last one does as it seems to be conceding the absence of “troubling” instead of establishing it as incontestable.